# How to make dragged UI element snap to position when overlapping slot

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm making a 2D puzzle game and I've been using the IPointerDownHandler, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler and IDropHandler to pick up, move and drop the puzzle tiles into the puzzle (everything mentioned is on a Canvas).
The game is working and all, but I noticed that the puzzle tiles snap into the correct position only when the mouse cursor is above the slot (not when the Image is covering it). How could I check if the UI Image is hovering above the slot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint.html) to test if the screen point is over the slot.  This is easiest to use in combination with a component on the slot containing one or more implementations of the `IPointer` interfaces.  Otherwise, iterate over the slots to check if the pointer is over one of them.

You could also test the element below using [EventSystem.current.RaycastAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.RaycastAll.html) or using the [GraphicRaycaster.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.GraphicRaycaster.Raycast.html) as shown in this post [how-to-raycast-onto-a-unity-canvas-ui-image](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-raycast-onto-a-unity-canvas-ui-image.855259/).

If the pointer is not over the object at all, but the puzzle tile is overlapping a slot, you can test overlap using [Rect.Overlaps](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect.Overlaps.html) from the RectTransforms `rect` property.

```
var puzzlePieceRect = thisPuzzlePieceRectTransform.rect;

foreach (var slotRectTransform in slotRectTransforms)
{
    if (puzzlePieceRect.Overlaps(slotRectTransform.rect))
    {
        Debug.Log($"Puzzle piece overlaps slot {slotRectTransform}");
        break;
    }
}
```